# ZF2 EdpDiscuss module usage

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I am new to ZF2. I am trying to use `EdpDiscuss` module, I've downloaded from [here](https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpDiscuss). I put the main file to modules, and added module to `application.config.php`. When I var_dump active modules

```
$modules = $this->getEvent()->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('modulemanager')->getLoadedModules();
$moduleNames = array_keys($modules);
var_dump($moduleNames);
```

It shows `EdpDiscuss` as it should, but how can I use it? There are no routes in `module.config.php` so it has no pages. I also tried to use it as service:

```
$service = $sm->getServiceLocator()->get('edpdiscuss');
```

but I was not succesfull either. Can you please tell me how to use this module?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example project you can use:
https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpForum

Basically, the service can be obtained with:

```
$discussService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('edpdiscuss_discuss_service');
```

After that, you can use methods of the service by exploring its public interface:

https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpDiscuss/blob/master/src/EdpDiscuss/Service/Discuss.php